# Array with a single element Javascript

Tags: javascript, vb.net, arrays

I have a site that dynamically creates two arrays of Lat/Long values based on the stores that the currently logged in user can see. If the user can only see one location then I get an error about array length needing to be a finite integer. When I look at the source I see

```
var ls =  new Array(45.056124);
```

is being created on the page dynamically which is what I'm expecting. Except I think it is treating it as if I am trying to set the length of the array instead of set the first element to that value.

How do I go about creating an array using the `ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration` function to hold a single double value using vb.net?

Comment: I found the answer thanks to Konrad Rudolph. I solved it by surrounding the value portion of the `ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration` call with double quotes and then implementing the javascript `parseFloat` function anywhere that the array was used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn’t [the documentation of the `RegisterArrayDeclaration`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerarraydeclaration.aspx) method give all the necessary information?

Your particular array would look as follows:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("ls", "45.056124")
```

Comment: Looking at the documentation again lead me to the `parseInt` function so expanding on that I found the `parseFloat` function and that did the trick. Guess I had just been looking at that page too much in the last few days so a step back was all it took.

Answer (score 5):

Try doing this:

```
var ls =  [45.056124]; //sets it as an array of one value
```

Comment: I'm using the ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration function to create the array so I think I'm locked into it being declared using the "new Array()" method

Answer (score 1):

This is one of JavaScript's *bad parts*. The `Array` constructor, when passed one `Number` argument (remember, in JavaScript all *number literals* are... `Number`s), initializes the array to a predefined length.

That means:

```
var ls = new Array(45);

ls.length === 45; // This is true
```

When passed a non-integer `Number`, the [`Array` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) throws a `RangeError` indicating that it isn't a valid length.

As a rule of thumb, as it already been said, always use the *array literal* to create arrays:

```
var ls = [45.056124];
```